# Program that helps you search for torrents

Tags: java

I wrote a desktop application in java (with JavaFX). Program first find given title in Imdb via: https://imdb-internet-movie-database-unofficial.p.rapidapi.com and then when user select a movie, search in the pirate bay site for magnets link, seeds and leechers.

Here is an example:

[image]

Here are two classes:

**ImdbFinder**

```
package service.movie;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import exception.NoMovieFoundException;
import model.Movie;
import service.util.JsonParserUtil;
import service.util.PropertyHelper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ImdbFinder implements MovieFinder {

    private static ImdbFinder instance;
    private static Properties properties;
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    private ImdbFinder() { }

    public static ImdbFinder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ImdbFinder();
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            properties = PropertyHelper.loadPropertyFileForFilename("ImdbHttpInfo.properties");
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public Movie getMovieDetailsForMovieId(String movieId) {
        return new Movie();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Movie> getMovieListForSearchedPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoMovieFoundException {
        List<Movie> movies = mapTitlesToMovieList(foundMovies(phrase).body());
        if (movies == null || movies.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoMovieFoundException();
        }
        return movies;
    }

    private List<Movie> mapTitlesToMovieList(String response) throws IOException {
        Optional<JsonArray> jsonArray = Optional.ofNullable(
                JsonParserUtil.parseStringToJsonObject(response).getAsJsonArray("titles"));

        List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (jsonArray.isPresent()) {
            movieList = objectMapper.readValue(jsonArray.get().toString(), new TypeReference<List<Movie>>() {});
        }

        return movieList;
    }

    private HttpResponse<String> foundMovies(String title) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(properties.getProperty("search-api-url") + formatTitle(title)))
                .header("x-rapidapi-key", properties.getProperty("x-rapidapi-key"))
                .header("x-rapidapi-host", properties.getProperty("x-rapidapi-host"))
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        System.out.println(URI.create(properties.getProperty("search-api-url") + formatTitle(title)));
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }

    private String formatTitle(String title) {
        return title.replaceAll("\\s+", "%20")
                .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\d\\s%]", "");
    }
}
```

**PirateBayFinder**

```
package service.torrent;

import exception.NoTorrentFoundException;
import model.Torrent;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PirateBayFinder implements TorrentFinder {

    private static TorrentFinder instance;

    private static final String SEARCH_URL = "https://tpb.party/search/";

    private static final String MAGNET_REGEX = "magnet:\\?xt=(.*?)(?=\")";
    private static final String TITLE_INSIDE_MAGNET_REGEX = "(?<=&dn=)(.*?)(?=&tr)";
    private static final String SEEDS_LECHERS_PATTERN = "(?<=<td align=\"right\">)([0-9]*?)(?=</td>)";

    private PirateBayFinder() { }

    public static TorrentFinder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new PirateBayFinder();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Torrent> findTorrentsForPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoTorrentFoundException {

        String htmlPage = foundTorrents(phrase).body();

        List<Torrent> foundTorrents = new ArrayList<>();

        scrapTorrentInfo(htmlPage, foundTorrents);
        scrapSeedsAndLeechers(htmlPage, foundTorrents);

        if (foundTorrents.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoTorrentFoundException();
        }

        return foundTorrents;
    }

    private void scrapTorrentInfo(String htmlPage, List<Torrent> foundTorrents) {
        Matcher magnetMatcher = Pattern.compile(MAGNET_REGEX).matcher(htmlPage);
        Pattern titlePattern = Pattern.compile(TITLE_INSIDE_MAGNET_REGEX);
        Matcher titleMatcher;
        String title;
        String magnet;
        while (magnetMatcher.find()) {
            magnet = magnetMatcher.group();
            titleMatcher = titlePattern.matcher(magnet);
            if (titleMatcher.find()) {
                title = titleMatcher.group();
                foundTorrents.add(new Torrent(title, magnet));
            }
        }
    }

    private void scrapSeedsAndLeechers(String htmlPage, List<Torrent> foundTorrents) {
        final Matcher seedsLeechersMatcher = Pattern.compile(SEEDS_LECHERS_PATTERN).matcher(htmlPage);
        int seeds, lecheers;
        int counter = 0;
        while(seedsLeechersMatcher.find()) {
            seeds = Integer.parseInt(seedsLeechersMatcher.group());
            lecheers = 0;
            if (seedsLeechersMatcher.find()) {
                lecheers = Integer.parseInt(seedsLeechersMatcher.group());
            }
            foundTorrents.get(counter).setSeeds(seeds);
            foundTorrents.get(counter).setLeechers(lecheers);
            counter++;
        }
    }

    private HttpResponse<String> foundTorrents(String title) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(SEARCH_URL + title.replaceAll("\\s+","%20")))
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        System.out.println(request.uri());
        return HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
}
```

and two interfaces:

**MovieFinder**

```
public interface MovieFinder {

    Movie getMovieDetailsForMovieId(String id);

    List<Movie> getMovieListForSearchedPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException;

}
```

**TorrentFinder**

```
public interface TorrentFinder {

    List<Torrent> findTorrentsForPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException;

}
```

Can you please tell me what I can improve these two classes? I think code which contains matchers and patterns looks too complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
package service.movie;
```

Package names normally associate the code with the author/organization, like "com.github.mrfisherman.moviefinder" or "com.company.ourapp".

---

```java
    public static ImdbFinder getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new ImdbFinder();
            objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            properties = PropertyHelper.loadPropertyFileForFilename("ImdbHttpInfo.properties");
        }
        return instance;
    }
```

That's not thread-safe, when invoked from multiple threads n instances might be created. There are three ways to fix it:

1. Create the instance in the `static` constructor. I'd advice against this as to not make it a habit, because if no instance is ever needed, one still might be created if only `static` fields or methods are accessed.
2. Make the whole method `synchronized`.
3. Use double-checked locking with a `volatile` field.

```java
private static volatile ImdbFinder instance;

public static ImdbFinder gestInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized(ImdbFinder.class) {
            if (instance == null) {
                // TODO Init instance here.
            }
        }
    }
    
    return instance;
}
```

---

```java
    private static Properties properties;
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

This seem to be better suited as instance fields.

---

```java
    @Override
    public Movie getMovieDetailsForMovieId(String movieId) {
        return new Movie();
    }
```

???

---

```java
public List<Movie> getMovieListForSearchedPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoMovieFoundException
```

If a method throws an `InterruptedException`, something smells.

---

```java
    @Override
    public List<Movie> getMovieListForSearchedPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException, NoMovieFoundException {
        List<Movie> movies = mapTitlesToMovieList(foundMovies(phrase).body());
        if (movies == null || movies.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoMovieFoundException();
        }
        return movies;
    }
```

Do not signal "no items found" with an `Exception`, return an empty list instead (not `null`). That will reduce the code using this function from having to use a `try...catch` block to maybe not even having to do an `if`.

---

```java
        Matcher titleMatcher;
        String title;
        String magnet;
        while (magnetMatcher.find()) {
            magnet = magnetMatcher.group();
            titleMatcher = titlePattern.matcher(magnet);
            if (titleMatcher.find()) {
                title = titleMatcher.group();
                foundTorrents.add(new Torrent(title, magnet));
            }
        }
```

This isn't C for some embedded system with low resources, this is Java. Whether you declare the variable outside the loop or not does not matter in the slightest, except for readability and maintainability. Declare your variables in the lowest scope possible.

---

```java
System.out.println(URI.create(properties.getProperty("search-api-url") + formatTitle(title)));
```

Don't print to stdout unless expected to. Use a logger, like the Java default one, and even then try to keep your logging as meaningful as possible. This seems more like a debug information you might need in certain circumstances then during the normal operation of the application.

---

```java
public interface MovieFinder {

    Movie getMovieDetailsForMovieId(String id);

    List<Movie> getMovieListForSearchedPhrase(String phrase) throws IOException, InterruptedException;

}
```

I always advice people to be as descriptive as possible in names, but that is a little bit too much. `Movie getMovie(String id)` and `List<Movie> findMovies(String searchterm)` tells me everything I need to know when looking at the API.

Additionally, `getMovieListForSearchedPhrase` should not declare `InterruptedException` and `IOException` (not every finder might do IO and therefor need), but should throw a specialized exception, like `MovieException` or `MovieFinderException`, if they *really* need to throw something. In this case, both might be fine without exceptions, as the first returns `null` if there is not movie, and the second returns an empty `List` if no movies were found. If you want to communicate failures, as they might be expected of some sort, then use the same specialized exception for both methods.

---

Last but not least, a word of warning regarding the law and legality. *Technically* what you do here is, without question, okay, as you're only providing a tool. However, *legally* it depends on the jurisdiction you are under. A tool with the sole purpose to break copyright is seen just as bad as breaking copyright on many parts of the world. Even if not directly illegally, there are groups ("representative of artists") which might *still* try to go against this.

If in doubt, ask a lawyer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this CR. This is what I needed. About last point, I left a note on github: [Attention!] I am not responsible for any misuse or any legal consequences of using the program. I also do not encourage you to download movies from illegal sources. The program was created for an educational purpose. hope it is enough for now because I don't share any illegal data etc.

Comment: "hope it is enough for now", as I said, technically yes, legally, ask a lawyer. Also keep in mind that the country of the *hosting service* is important in these questions. Overall, what might also be a nice design exercise, is to not make it a "MovieFinder" but a "TorrentFinder" which sports the ability to match different items against torrents. So, the IMDB one just becomes one of many implementations, for another to find Linux distributions, or abandoned games, or public domain books and so forth.

Comment: I have one more question, I know you say that I shouldn't throw exceptions outside of methods but I did it to catch them all in Controller when I can show gui alert to the user. So what should I do now, leave it like it is and catch them later or as you said try catch them in same method.

Comment: Use a dedicated exception, as I've pointed out. The problem here is, as I've said, that throwing `InterruptedException` is odd, and an implementation detail. So is throwing an `IOException`. The interface should not depend on behavior of an implementation, but both of these are implementation specific exceptions. The best way would be to provide a generic, custom exception, as said, which is being thrown from both methods if you need to signal that an exception occurred during these methods. That means that implemenations catch any specific exceptions, and rethrow them as custom ones.